# Dúvida em exercício com fatorial e números grandes

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um exercício que pede o valor de Y dado por **Y = x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4! + ...** , considerando os 15 primeiros termos.
Estou tendo problemas porque os resultados fatoriais a partir do 10 termo já começam a ficar gigantes. Para isso, usei long long int. 
CREIO que seja a parte do **do**(operações) que esteja errada, porque tentei mudando o contPotencia para <= 3, e testei o programa colocando x = 2 e o resultado teria que ser 6. Mesmo assim, deu um número absurdo de grande. O que pode estar ocorrendo também pode ser os tipos das variáveis estarem errados, mas não sei mais o que tentar para arrumar isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //VARIAVEIS
    unsigned long long int valorX, cont = 3, contPotencia = 1, fat = 2, potencia, x;
    float divisao, resultado;

    //INICIO
    printf("Insira X: ");
    scanf("%llu", &valorX);

    if (valorX < 1){
        printf("Número inválido, insira um maior que 0.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Y = %llu", valorX);
        x = valorX;
        do {
            x = valorX*x;
            printf(" + %llu/%llu ", x, fat);
            contPotencia++;

            fat = cont*fat;
            cont++;

            divisao = x/fat;

            resultado = resultado+divisao;

        } while (contPotencia < 15);
    }
    printf("\nY = %f", resultado);

}
```

Comment: Acho que ficaria melhor se você fizesse uma função recursiva para calcular o fatorial.

Comment: Qual é o erro que tu estás tendo? Há alguma mensagem? Eu, particularmente, não entendi a tua dúvida...

Comment: Minha dúvida é se a parte das operações que está errada ou se são os tipos de dados que usei para declarar as variáveis. É que como estou trabalhando com números grandes, pode ser isso. Mas acredito que seja a própria parte da operação mesmo... só não sei o que consertar.

Comment: @WhoisMatt Nesse caso não precisa de uma função só pra calcular o fatorial. No primeiro termo o denominador é 1!, no segundo é 2!, no terceiro é 3!, etc, então basta guardar o valor anterior e a cada iteração, multiplicar pelo próximo valor (algo [assim](https://ideone.com/bmy8jq)). E se ainda sim quiser uma função separada, um loop é bem mais eficiente (e simples) para calcular fatorial do que recursão :-)

Comment: Valeu @hkotsubo, agora que disse percebi que é mais simples assim. Obrigado!

Comment: Qual é a definição de x? Você faz if (x < 1){ mas não existe nenhuma atribuição a tal variável.

Comment: O certo era if (valorX<1). Eu deveria revisar mais meus códigos antes de postá-los aqui...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui responder o exercício e chegar no resultado esperado. O problema era na própria ordem das operações.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    //VARIAVEIS
    unsigned long long int valorX, cont = 3, contPotencia = 1;
    float divisao, resultado, fat = 2, x;

     //INICIO
    printf("Insira X: ");
    scanf("%llu", &valorX);

    if (valorX < 1){
        printf("Número inválido, insira um maior que 0.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Y = %llu", valorX);
        x = valorX;
        resultado = x;
        do {
            x = valorX*x;
            printf(" + %.f/%.f", x, fat);

             divisao = x/fat;

            fat = cont*fat;

            contPotencia++;
            cont++;

            resultado = resultado+divisao;

        } while (contPotencia < 15);
    }
    printf("\nResultado = %f", resultado);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Problema 1: você tem que fazer as contas em ponto flutuante, senão o resultado da divisão de x/y quando x < y vai ser 0.

Problema 2: a variável "resultado" precisa ser inicializada.

Fiz um teste (bem) rápido, parece que está funcionando.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  //VARIAVEIS
  double valorX, cont = 3, contPotencia = 1, fat = 2, potencia, x;
  float divisao, resultado = 0;

  //INICIO
  printf("Insira X: ");
  scanf("%lf", &valorX);

  // if (x < 1){ // <------ erro
  if (valorX < 1) {
    printf("Número inválido, insira um maior que 0.");
  }
  else {
    printf("Y = %lf", valorX);
    x = valorX;
    do {
      x = valorX*x;
      printf(" + %lf/%lf ", x, fat);
      contPotencia++;

      fat = cont*fat;
      cont++;

      divisao = x/fat;
      printf("\n*");
      printf("\n* x=%lf fat=%lf divisao=%f", x, fat, divisao);

      resultado = resultado+divisao;
      printf("\n* resultado: %f", resultado);

    } while (contPotencia <= 3);
  }

  printf("\n*");
  printf("\nY = %f", resultado);
}
```

Teste:

```
$ 380126.exe                                           
Insira X: 2                                            
Y = 2.000000 + 4.000000/2.000000                       
*                                                      
* x=4.000000 fat=6.000000 divisao=0.666667             
* resultado: 0.666667 + 8.000000/6.000000              
*                                                      
* x=8.000000 fat=24.000000 divisao=0.333333            
* resultado: 1.000000 + 16.000000/24.000000            
*                                                      
* x=16.000000 fat=120.000000 divisao=0.133333          
* resultado: 1.133333                                  
*                                                      
Y = 1.133333                                           

$
```

Comment: Cara, me equivoquei e fiz uma confusão legal no post, perdão. Eu postei meu código teste sem querer, com o contPotencia <= 3 para ficar mais fácil para conferir o resultado. Eu entendi o seu código e realmente deu certo para uma sequência pequena de números, mas o problema é que o exercício pede os 15 primeiros termos. Ou seja, chega um momento que os números começam a ficar tão grandes que o resultado dá errado. Foi por isso que usei long long int. Então, creio que o problema seja exatamente no tipo de variáveis.

Comment: até 17! deve caber num double...se precisar, use um long double no lugar de double

Comment: use um "long double" no lugar de "double" (adaptando também o formato %lf para %Lf no printf) (o comentário anterior que fiz está incompleto e errado)

Comment: ops, respondendo agora uma outra pergunta deu pra ver que neste seu caso nem precisa usar long double, usando apenas double jpa é suficiente